# Invalid susername_sname()/SYSTEM_USER returned after AD login creditentials were changed

Tags: sql-server

We are using `suser_sname()` and `SYSTEM_USER` to return the user name (via trust connection). Within the past month, someone's login name was changed in Active Directory. However these 2 functions are still returning the old login name.

The individual has rebooted their PC several times since the change. I'm not sure if the servers were rebooted since then. One of them will be rebooted tomorrow, which we are assuming will remedy the situation for the one server.

Is there another way for SQL Server to recognize this change without rebooting (assuming that rebooting fixes it).

**EDIT:**
The individual's login doesn't exist in SQL Server, but AD Groups in which they are a member, are on the server.

e.g., 
*Domain\AtticusFinch is not setup in SQL, but Domain\Lawyers does exist. In this case, Atticus' login was changed to Domain\AtticusF1*

**EDIT 2:**
Simply stopping and starting the SQL Service doesn't remedy the problem. Rebooting, however, did fix it.

Comment: Is the login specifically set up? Or is access via groups only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this before but it's been some time.

I only saw it for login where there was an entry in sys.server_principals. Not purely via group membership.

Try this using [ALTER LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

```
ALTER LOGIN [domain\oldlogin] WITH NAME = [domain\newlogin]
```

Comment: My bad. AD group(s) were setup (i.e. Domain\Users ); the individual's login was never explicitly setup on the server. It's as if the system is caching their old login. So, Altering the login will not work, since it doesn't exist.

Comment: The system does cache unfortunately. AFAIK, you'd have to restart SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946358/en-us

---

To work around this issue, disable the local SID cache on the domain member computer. To do this, follow these steps:
1.  Open Registry Editor.

To do this in Windows XP or in Windows Server 2003, click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.

To do this in Windows Vista and newer, Click Start, type regedit in the Start Search box, and then press ENTER.

1. Locate and then right-click the following registry subkey:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
2. Point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
3. Type LsaLookupCacheMaxSize, and then press ENTER.
4. Right-click LsaLookupCacheMaxSize, and then click Modify.
5. In the Value data box, type 0, and then click OK.
6. Exit Registry Editor.

---

I add, after doing this you must restart your machine.

---

Then, after renaming in AD the user must relogin, and

```
dbcc freesystemcache('ALL')
```

must be executed on the sql server.

Answer (score 1):

We had this same problem. Database permissions were set up using an AD group, and a member of the group had their username changed but the system_user function was still returning the old username. We were able to resolve without a restart by creating a login for the affected user, then deleting it, e.g:

```
CREATE LOGIN [domain\newlogin] FROM WINDOWS;

DROP LOGIN [domain\newlogin];
```

Comment: This only works once `execute as login='domain\newlogin';revert` is successful. For me the new login was not recognized by the SQL Server even after a few weeks, until I managed to run `dbcc freesystemcache('ALL')` (during the maintenance window.)

Answer (score 0):

See if using `SUSER_SNAME(SUSER_SID())` instead of `SUSER_SNAME()` makes a difference.

Comment: No, this makes no difference. The old user name is returned.